# API Design that Caches an External API

Tags: ruby, api, caching

I have built a lightweight Ruby code to wrap an external API:

```
api = ExternalAPI.new
api.expensive_operation(object)
```

It works fine. However, since the API is expensive, I don't want to call it unless necessary. This is why I am creating a higher-level API that wraps the API call with local caching. I don't want the application to have to worry about the details about how the API is cached. (Caching could be accomplished by memory, disk, [abaci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus), even [pigeons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers) -- it is not the application's concern.)

Here is what I am currently considering:

```
wrapper = ExternalAPIWrapper.new
wrapper.expensive_operation(object)
```

I don't like about the name `ExternalAPIWrapper`. It is generic, does not convey the **purpose** of the wrapper. In particular, it does not indicate that it is checks a local cache first and only hits the low-level API if necessary.

I'm looking for answers that improve upon this starting point. Here are some things I'm looking for:

1. A better name for the high-level class
2. A better style API
3. Design pattern(s) that might help
4. (Perhaps a longshot...) a Ruby gem that wraps and caches API calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #1 the name that comes to mind is `CachedExternalAPI`:) Not sure what you mean by "a better style API", though.

As for #3/4: I don't know of a RubyGem that does this sort of caching thing, but I'd implement the cached API in a "metaprogramming" fashion, automatically generating the methods for the cached API calls, e.g.

```
class CachedExternalAPI
  @cache = { }

  class << self

    [:foo, :bar, :baz].each do |m|
      define_method m do
        return (puts "Totally cached!"; @cache[m]) if not @cache[m].nil?
        puts "Not cached :("
        @cache[m] = 42
      end
    end

  end
end

CachedExternalAPI.foo()
CachedExternalAPI.foo()

CachedExternalAPI.bar()
CachedExternalAPI.bar()
```

Which will yield

> Not cached :(
>   Totally cached!
>   Not cached :(
>   Totally cached!

This of course assumes that the caching mechanism for all API calls is the same. But if your API is cachable that way, you can keep the cached API wrapper pretty DRY.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. `CachedExternalAPI` is an improvement on the name. I don't think the code itself is quite what I'm looking for, but it illustrates your point very well.

Comment: @DavidJames Don't get me wrong, I sure don't want you to use the code exactly as posted. When caching the requests you should of course not do it in a class-variable. But instead of that variable, you could simply call a method that caches your request to disk or wherever you want it to be cached :)

Comment: roger that. I'm glad you provided code -- it was above and beyond what I asked for! Getting the details right is my job, not yours :)

Answer (score 2):

Rob, a friend of mine, found [APICache](https://github.com/mloughran/api_cache):

> APICache (aka api_cache)
>
> APICache allows any API client library to be easily wrapped with a robust caching layer. It supports caching (obviously), serving stale data and limits on the number of API calls. It's also got a handy syntax if all you want to do is cache a bothersome url.

APICache supports multiple caching strategies, including:

- A simple in-memory cache
- Various backends via [Moneta](https://github.com/wycats/moneta), a "unified interface to key-value stores"
- Memcached via [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli), named after Dalí's Persistence of Memory

Answer (score 0):

Too little detail to know exactly what you want but I thought of a bridge pattern straight away since you are essentially trying to decouple your abstraction and implementation when looking at varying your cache backend.

Comment: According to http://designpatternsinruby.com/section02/bridge.html "The bridge is a a kind of double ended adapter, which completely decouples an abstraction from its implementation. I tend to think of this as more of an antipattern than a pattern. Also very rarely used in my experience." Mr Morphe, do you disagree?

Comment: A double ended adaptor is an interesting analogy since many people think of the bridge as a solution to combinatorial explosion in a class hierarchy which is what Mr Olsen is referring to. I'm thinking of the bridge pattern in terms of where I've encountered examples such as persistence engine which is no doubt why it sprang to mind. As to being very rarely used...well Mr Olsen also doesn't have much use for the mediator pattern....

Comment: Can you help make this concrete for me? Another source I read, http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/060-issue-26-structural-design-patterns.html, struggles to find a practical reason why you would need to use the Bridge Pattern in Ruby.

Comment: Also, you wrote "too little detail to know exactly what you want." What else do you need to know? The details of the web service should not matter -- but to be safe, let's assume it is well behaved as a Resource Oriented Architecture (as explained by [Richardson and Ruby](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do)). I want to be open to different caching back-ends, as I mentioned.

Comment: Too little detail because I don't know the entirety of your design or what problems you are looking to insulate yourself from. I had a quick read of Mr Gregory's blog and he makes a fair point regarding duck-type semantics, although this is an implementation detail rather than a design detail which is why I think Mr Gregory struggles to find non-contrived examples. I'm in the middle of a house move at the moment otherwise I'd expand on this...